# Execution failed for task App:dexDebug UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: Multiple dex files define

Tags: java, android, xml

A newbie.. Please solve this issue.. when i try to compile appcompat v7 library i get this multiple dex files define build error.. Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
Here is the code::

MainActivity.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Currency;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.OnNavigationListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.ShareCompat;


@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale") public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
protected static final int REQUEST_OK = 1;
ListView l1;
ArrayList<Array_songs> songlist;
EditText e1;
Song_adapter adp;
private ShareActionProvider MenuSAP;

ImageButton ib;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    //actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.iconw);

    l1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv1);
    ib=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ib1);
    songlist=new ArrayList<Array_songs>();
    e1= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    e1.addTextChangedListener(tw);

    ib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent i=new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
            try{
                startActivityForResult(i,REQUEST_OK );
            }catch(ActivityNotFoundException r){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"song cant be played", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


        }
    });


    adp=new Song_adapter(MainActivity.this, songlist, this.getApplication());
    l1.setAdapter(adp);
    getSongList("");


    l1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long arg3) {

            int sCB = getVar();
            if(sCB == 0) {
                Array_songs slist = songlist.get(position);
                String Song_Title = slist.get_title();
                String Song_Artist = slist.get_artist();
                long Song_ID = slist.get_id();


                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Song_Artist + Song_Title + String.valueOf(Song_ID), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Uri song_path = ContentUris.withAppendedId(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, Song_ID);


                Intent musicplayer = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                musicplayer.setDataAndType(song_path, "audio/*");

                try {

                    startActivity(musicplayer);

                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }
            else
            {

            }

        }
    });



    l1.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            changeVar();
            vibrate();
            int select = l1.getSelectedItemPosition();
            l1.setItemChecked(select, true);
            adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return false;
        }
    });
}

private void vibrate() {
    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    v.vibrate(120);
}


private void changeVar() {
    ((SyncClass) this.getApplication()).setShowCheckBox(1);
}



private int getVar()
{
    Integer sCB = Integer.parseInt(((SyncClass) this.getApplication()).getShowCheckBox());
    return sCB;
}



TextWatcher tw=new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        songlist.clear();
        adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
        getSongList(s.toString());



    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                  int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};



protected void  onActivityResult(int requestcode,int resultcode,Intent data){

    super.onActivityResult(requestcode, resultcode, data);

    if(requestcode==REQUEST_OK && resultcode==RESULT_OK){
        ArrayList<String> ls=data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

        e1.setText(ls.get(0));

    }


}



public void getSongList(String stitle){
    ContentResolver cr= getContentResolver();
    Uri music=android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor mus=cr.query(music, null, null, null, null);

    if(mus != null && mus.moveToFirst()){

        int titleint=mus.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int artistint= mus.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        int songid=mus.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        do{
            String songTitle=mus.getString(titleint);
            String songArtist=mus.getString(artistint);
            long  songId=mus.getLong(songid);

            if(songTitle.toUpperCase().contains(stitle.toUpperCase())){


                songlist.add(new Array_songs(songId, songTitle, songArtist));

            }

        }while(mus.moveToNext());

    }

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
    MenuSAP = new ShareActionProvider(this);
    MenuSAP.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
    MenuItemCompat.setActionProvider(item, MenuSAP);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private Intent createShareIntent() {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("audio/*");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES,"audio/*");
    return shareIntent;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    int check;
    check = getVar();
    if(check == 1)
    {
        ((SyncClass) this.getApplication()).setShowCheckBox(0);
        adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    else
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

}

SongAdapter.java

```
public class Song_adapter extends BaseAdapter {
private ArrayList<Array_songs> song_ob;
private LayoutInflater inflator_ob;
private Application xyz;
//private int sCB = ((SyncClass) this.getApplication()).getSomeVariable();
public Song_adapter(Context c,ArrayList<Array_songs> songlist, Application a)
{
    song_ob=songlist;
    inflator_ob= LayoutInflater.from(c);
    xyz = a;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return song_ob.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LinearLayout lin_ob =(LinearLayout)inflator_ob.inflate(R.layout.song_content, parent,false) ;
    Array_songs ars_ob= song_ob.get(position);
    TextView title= (TextView)lin_ob.findViewById(R.id.song_name);
    TextView artist= (TextView)lin_ob.findViewById(R.id.artist);
    //CheckBox check = (CheckBox) lin_ob.findViewById(R.id.cbselect);
    if(((SyncClass) xyz).getShowCheckBox() == "1")
    {
        lin_ob.findViewById(R.id.cbselect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        lin_ob.findViewById(R.id.cbselect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    String stitle= ars_ob.get_title();
    String sartist= ars_ob.get_artist();

    title.setText(stitle);
    artist.setText(sartist);


    return lin_ob;

}
```

}

SyncClass.java

```
public class SyncClass extends Application {
private String showCheckBox = "0";

public String getShowCheckBox()
{
    return showCheckBox;
}

public void setShowCheckBox(int showCheckBox)
{
    this.showCheckBox = Integer.toString(showCheckBox);
}
```

}

menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"      tools:context=".MainActivity"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Share"
    android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
```

build.gradle(Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.musicginni"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.+'
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+"
}
```

Logcat:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
C:\Users\Arpit\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output H:\AndroidStudioProjects\MusixMatch\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=H:\AndroidStudioProjects\MusixMatch\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
2
Output:
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBar$LayoutParams;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 4.112 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied two jar files one for Appcompat v7 and other for v4 in my app-> libs folder that was causing the error.. Once I removed those jar files.. It is now working fine..